# Youtube embed breaks my website

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

I embedded a Youtube video in my website using iframe. However, I get multiple errors in the console and it breaks my script so stuff like menu stops working.

My html (Pug) looks like this:

```
iframe(src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rgPzdwRT1tE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen)
```

And the errors are as follows:

```
GET chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED
```

The embedded video plays just fine.

I've already read several older SO questions regarding similar errors but they aren't helpful. I must be missing something obvious because this is seemingly not a problem that other people face.

Same result on Chrome and Opera. Edge does not display any errors but my script is still broken. Tested both locally and when hosted.

Comment: The same errors in Edge, really? And how about Firefox?

Comment: @Ryan sorry, no errors in Edge but the script is still broken. I will edit my question to clarify that. I will also try Firefox.

Comment: Where is your script in the template? If it’s external, is it showing up in the network panel?

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, the script was missing in the template. The errors are still but I will deal will them later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it has nothing to do with the embed, I just did not include the html component with my script. I feel stupid for not checking/noticing but the errors threw me off I guess.